# Why do I still have margin when I use margin: 0; on that element

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm writing the media query for a large phone screen. When the footer section is displayed at this size, I want to remove the margin on divs  with the class 'inner', and have them lined up on the left side of the screen . this removes the margin on the quick link's div but not the social and the contact sections. They still have a left margin?[image]

```css
body, html {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

/*---HEADER---*/

li a {
 text-decoration-line: none;
 color: rgba(102,102,102,0.75);
}

.m1, .m2, .m3 {
 border-radius: 4px;
 margin: 5px;
 width: 45px;
 height: 5px;
 background-color: red;
 float: left;
}

header {
 background: blue;
 height: 100vh;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}

nav {
 background-color: white;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 2;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px grey;
}

ul {
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-top: 25px;
}

li {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 1.55rem;
 margin-right: 20px;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
}

li a:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #1a1a1a;
 transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

.after:after {
 position: relative;
 left: 12px;
 top: 2px;
 display: inline-block;
 content: "";
 width: 1px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102,0.25);
}

.logo {
 color: red;
 font-size: 3.7rem;
 margin: 10px;
 opacity: 1;
 margin-left: 30px;
}

.phrase {
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 top: 300px;
}

.phrase p {
 color: white;
 font-size: 3.5rem;
 font-family: 'Arvo';
 margin-bottom: 30px;

}

.phrase a {
 background-color: red;
 border-radius: 25px;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Bitter';
 font-size: 1.8rem;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-top: 10px;
}

.phrase a:hover {
 background-color: #cc2900;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.phrase .fas {
 display: block;
 color: white;
 font-size: 3.5rem;
 margin-top: 15px;
}

/*---PROMISE---*/

.stats {
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px grey;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
 background-color: white;
}

.stats div {
 display: inline-block;
 flex-basis: 35%;
 text-align: center;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.stats p {
 font-size: 2rem;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 margin-bottom: 0;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.stats div:before {
 display: inline-block;
 content: '';
 width: 2px;
 height: 35px;
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.60);
}

.promise {
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url('../img/concrete.jpg');
 background-position: center;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover;
}

.promise .wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.promise h1 {
 position: relative;
 top: 40px;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Arvo';
 font-size: 3.5rem;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 0;
 word-spacing: 7px;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 100px grey;
}

.promise p {
 color: white;
 font-size: 1.8rem;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 margin-bottom: 0;
 padding-bottom: 60px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 40px;
 padding-left: 50px;
 padding-right: 50px;
}

/*---FOOTER---*/

.footer .wrapper {
 display: flex;
}

.footer div {
 display: inline-block;
 flex-basis: 33.33%;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 margin-top: 5px;
}

.footer h1 {
 font-size: 2rem;
 margin-top: 15px;
}

.footer .inner {
 margin-left: 70px;
}

.footer .inner:before {
 display: inline-block;
 content: '';
 width: 27.1%;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.6);
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 54px;
}


.links .inner:after {
 content: '';
 width: 10.5%;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -151px;
}

.social .inner:after {
 content: '';
 width: 5.8%;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -171px;
}

.contact .inner:after {
 content: '';
 width: 7.5%;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -174.5px;
}


.wrap:before {
 content: '';
 width: 100px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 55px;
}

.links a {
 display: block;
 text-decoration-line: none;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
 transition: color 0.4s ease;
}

.links a:hover {
 color: red;
}

.contact p {
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
}

.social i {
 font-size: 1.7rem;
 margin-right: 5px;
 position: relative;
 top: -20px;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.7);
 transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.social i:hover {
 color: red;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#msg {
 margin-top: -15px;
}

.footer-textarea {
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.2);
 outline: none;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 resize: none;
 width: 100%;
}

.footer button {
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 23.2%;
 margin-top: -40px;
 border: none;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 transition: all ease 0.4s;
 outline: none;
}

button:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: red;
}

.dark {
 color: red;
}

.copyright {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: white;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 padding-bottom: 4px;
}

/*---MEDIA QUERIES---*/

@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {

 /*---NAV---*/

 .logo {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-left: 10px;
 }

 ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }

 nav li {
  display: none;
 }

 .ham-menu {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .footer div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Rajdhani';
  color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
 }

 .footer .inner {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer .inner:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  width: 27.1%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 54px;
 }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intitial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Kane Concrete & Construction LLC</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo|Bitter|Lato|Montserrat|Noto+Sans|Open+Sans|Poppins|Roboto|Sarabun|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Asap|Krub|Oxygen|Rajdhani|Staatliches|Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="inner-wrap">
  <header>
   <nav>
    <div class="logo">
     <i class="fab fa-accusoft"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
     <div class="ham-menu">
      <div class="m1"></div>
      <div class="m2"></div>
      <div class="m3"></div>
     </div>
     <ul>
      <li class="after"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="about.html#services">Services</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </nav>
   
   <div class="phrase">
    <p>It all starts at the foundation.</p>
    <a>Get a Quote</a>
    <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
   </div> 
  </header>

  <section class="stats">
   <div id="start-year">
    <p>Established</p><br>
    <p style="color: red; font-size: 2.3rem; font-family: 'Roboto'; font-weight: bold;">2015</p>
   </div>

   <div id="projects">
    <p>Projects</p><br>
    <p style="color: red; font-size: 2.3rem; font-family: 'Roboto'; font-weight: bold;">200+</p>
   </div>

   <div id="claims">
    <p>Insurance claims</p><br>
    <p style="color: red; font-size: 2.3rem; font-family: 'Roboto'; font-weight: bold;">87%</p>
   </div>
  </section>

  <section class="promise">
   <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Our Promise</h1>

    <p><span style="color: red;">W</span>e believe that Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum doloremque impedit laudantium magnam eos quae ipsum, rem, dolorum saepe laboriosam ipsam nobis architecto debitis, vel aut provident tenetur perferendis, aliquid commodi magni sequi hic quia nemo! Nam odio fugiat, similique eum saepe. Laboriosam officiis delectus reiciendis, est tenetur voluptates ducimus! Ducimus enim dolor, eos id porro, amet culpa alias sunt reprehenderit necessitatibus deserunt eum. Sunt quia accusamus facilis quo, cum maiores nam illum sit quisquam, tempora fugit? Quod voluptate debitis voluptatum illo. Est, rerum sequi. Corporis atque incidunt placeat aliquam error veniam quis, minus voluptatem, qui, a pariatur voluptatibus, ut. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe labore aliquid magnam velit, nisi consequuntur!</p>
   </div>
  </section>
 </div>

 <section class="footer">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="links">
    <div class="inner">
     <h1>Quick Links</h1>

     <a href="#">Home</a>
     <a href="#">About</a>
     <a href="#">Services</a>
     <a href="#">Job Openings</a>
     <a href="#">Gallery</a>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="social">
    <div class="inner" style="margin-left: 45px;">
     <h1>Social</h1>

     <i class="fab fa-linkedin"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>
     <i class="fab fa-facebook"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>
     <i class="fab fa-twitter-square"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>

     <p id="msg">Give us some feedback!</p>
     <button name="msg">Send</button>
     <textarea name="msg" class="footer-textarea" cols="46" rows="5" placeholder="type here..."></textarea>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="contact">
    <div class="inner" style="margin-left: 20px;" class="wrap">
     <h1>Contact</h1>

     <p>(208)546-7827 - <span class="dark">Matt</span></p>
     <p>(208)546-7827 - <span class="dark">Keegan</span></p>
     <p><span class="dark">Address</span> - P.O. Box 50860 IF, ID 83405</p>
     <p><span class="dark">Email</span> - KaneConcrete@fake.com</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="copyright">&copy; 2019 - Kane Concrete & Construction | ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</div>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check well your code, you have set an inline style with that margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in your HTML-document, you have

```
<div class="inner" style="margin-left: 45px;">
```

applied inline to that element.

It's generally bad practice to write CSS inline using `<div style="">`.

Comment: Dang I can't believe  missed that

Answer (score -1):

try this instead

```
<div class="social">
            <div class="inner">
                <h1>Social</h1>

                <i class="fab fa-linkedin"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>
                <i class="fab fa-facebook"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>
                <i class="fab fa-twitter-square"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>

                <p id="msg">Give us some feedback!</p>
                <button name="msg">Send</button>
                <textarea name="msg" class="footer-textarea" cols="46" rows="5" placeholder="type here..."></textarea>
            </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  When you provide an answer, you should attempt to address the question statement, and then explain your answer.  in this instance, the Original Poster (OP) is asking "Why do I still have [a] margin...".  So the actual answer to such a question is to clarify or address the OP's misconception, since there is a failed expectation here.